# Can you call a constexpr function to assign a constexpr value with a forward declaration?

Tags: c++

I found myself in a weird spot, with the error message "expression did not evaluate to a constant":

```
constexpr uint64 createDynamicPipelineStateMask();

static inline constexpr uint64 dynamic_state_mask = createDynamicPipelineStateMask();


struct CullMode
{
    static constexpr inline bool bIsDynamicState = false;
    static constexpr inline uint64 mask = 0;
};

constexpr uint64 createDynamicPipelineStateMask()
{
    uint64 dynamic_mask = 0;
    if constexpr (CullMode::bIsDynamicState) dynamic_mask |= CullMode::mask;

    return dynamic_mask;
}
```

Now I guess I could just move the constexpr value to below the definition, but I wanted to know the answer to this question. I know that it's compiler, and not the linker that needs the full definition of the constexpr function, but the compiler has it right below.

Comment: No, compilers work from top to bottom in the file. At the point it needs to initialise `dynamic_state_mask` it doesn't know there is a definition of `createDynamicPipelineStateMask`

Comment: What is the purpose of `static` _and_ `inline` here on `dynamic_state_mask`? As far a I can tell `static` combined with `inline` on a namespace scope variable can only have negative effects (if any at all). Just `static` should be fine (and `constexpr` will imply `static` via its `const` effect as well, so just `constexpr` also has the same effect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that it's compiler, and not the linker that needs the full definition of the constexpr function, **but the compiler has it right below**.

The behavior of the program can be understood using [expr.const#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5) which states:

> **5.** An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:
>
> **5.2** **an invocation of an undefined constexpr function**;

(emphasis mine)

This means that when writing

```
//------------vvvvvvvvv--------------------------> note the constexpr here, this is not allowed because the call expression cannot be used in a constexpr context until the function is defined
static inline constexpr int dynamic_state_mask = createDynamicPipelineStateMask();
```

the **call expression** `createDynamicPipelineStateMask()` at this point is an invocation of an undefined constexpr function and so the initializer is not a constant expression according to the above quoted statement which in turn means that it cannot be used as an initializer to initialize `dynamic_state_mask`. Basically, you can't use the call expression `createDynamicPipelineStateMask()` in a **constexpr context** until the function is defined.

---

But the following is perfectly fine.

```
//------------v-------------------------->note no constexpr here, this is allowed
static inline  int dynamic_state_mask = createDynamicPipelineStateMask();
```

This time, even though `createDynamicPipelineStateMask()` does not evaulate to a constant expression, it can still be used as an initializer to initialize `dynamic_state_mask` as we have removed the `constexpr` specifier from the left hand side of the declaration. Basically this isn't a **constexpr context** and so using the call expression as an initializer is fine.

---

Perhaps a contrived example might clear this further:

```
constexpr int func();

//constexpr int i = func();   //not allowed as the call expression func() at this point is an invocation of an undefined constexpr function and so the initializer is not a constant expression

int i = func();               //allowed
constexpr int func()
{
    return 4;
}
constexpr int j = func();     //allowed
```

[Demo Clang&Gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/7Wzofz19h),

[MSVC Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jW8GGzqTj)